# Rails I18n changes apostrophe to ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, responders

I'm using [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem, and I want to show validation errors when form is not valid. In my controller I created the `interpolation_action`

```
def interpolation_options
  { resource_errors: @project_user.errors.full_messages.join(', ') }
end
```

and my reponders translation file has a proper key:

```
project_users:
  create:
    notice: "Member has been added"
    alert: "%{resource_errors}"
```

It works well and I can see validation error message, the problem is that apostrophe is changed to ASCII code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Responder still require you to add the flash in your html? In that case you could do something like `<%= flash[:alert].html_safe %>` to enforce html on your flash message, even for the escaped characters.

Comment: This is potentially dangerous. If you go this way, you have to ensure that you manually escape all user-provided data which might be shown in the flash (e.g. "'foo bar baz' is not a valid Flurb"). If you fail to escape the values manually, you have an XSS vulnerability.